# How to check files present or not in directory with mask defined in variable

Tags: bash, glob

I have bash script, which list files with mask

```
OFFSET1=`date +%y%m%d -d "2 day ago"`
```

and move their in another directory.
Files format for example - `*160123*.log`
Need to check, if files with mask $OFFSET1 exists, then move their in directory $DIR, else exit script.

I tried like

```
if [ -r *$OFFSET1* ];then
```

But nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
OFFSET1=$(date +%y%m%d -d "2 day ago")
for f in *"$OFFSET1"*;
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

You should [use `$()` syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) instead of backticks, and then use [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) to list the files. Remember to quote `$f` in your `mv` statement, in case of files with spaces in them.

Comment: No problem. In addition to marking an answer accepted if it solved your problem, you can also vote it up if you found it helpful. Not required but always appreciated.